# Given that $ \{ \vec{u}, \vec{v} \}$ are l.i. prove that if $ \vec{w} \times \vec{u} = \vec{w} \times \vec{v} = \vec{0}$ then $\vec{w} = \vec{0}$

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am asked to elaborate on the following proof:

> Given that $ \{ \vec{u}, \vec{v} \}$ are linearly independent prove that if $ \vec{w} \times \vec{u} = \vec{w} \times \vec{v} = \vec{0}$ then $\vec{w} = \vec{0}$. How would you interpret it geometrically?

For the first part (the proof) I am honestly lost. I am not sure you can make such a proof algebraically.

For the second part, I would say that $\vec{w}$ cannot be parallel to $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ given that they are not parallel to each other ( since $\{ \vec{u}, \vec{v} \}$ are linearly independent).

Is my reasoning for the second part correct? Is there a way to prove the first part?

**Possible answer for the first part:**

$$
\Vert \vec{w} \times \vec{u} \Vert = \Vert \vec{w} \Vert \Vert \vec{u} \Vert \sin{\theta_1}\\
\Vert \vec{w} \times \vec{v} \Vert = \Vert \vec{w} \Vert \Vert \vec{v} \Vert \sin{\theta_2}
\\
\vec{u} \neq \vec{0} \text{ and } \vec{v} \neq \vec{0} \text{ since } \{ \vec{u}, \vec{v} \} \text{ are linearly independent so } \vec{w} = \vec{0}
$$

Comment: I think your reasoning for the second part is already proof.

Comment: I've updated the answer for the first part of the question.

Comment: @bru1987 well, you should consider the case $\theta_1 = 0$ which then boils down to the proof of Tsemo.

Comment: mmm I see. But that would mean that definitely $\sin(\theta_2) \neq 0$ right?

Comment: @bru1987 no, it might be that $\theta_2=0$, so in fact you have to consider more cases....

Comment: What I mean is if $\sin(\theta_1) = 0$ then $\sin(\theta_2) \neq 0$ (or the opposite) since u and v are not parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$w\times u=w\times v=0$ implies that $w=au=bv, a,b\in R$ which is equivalent to $au-bv=0$ since $u,v$ linear independent $a=b=0$ and $ w=0$.

Comment: Thats a  great insight, thanks!